# How to convert GMap.net to COM component?

Tags: c#, com, gmap.net

I can't use GMap.net in Delphi.
It's need to convert GMap dll to COM component.
But how to do it? thanks.

I need the GMap offline mode for my project.
Can anybody help me convert the component?
Or how to complier GMap to COM component in C#?

Comment: This is a C# question! I have added C# tag and removed Delphi tag.

Comment: The GMap.Net source code as below
https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET
Can it be packaged into COM component?